# How to get minimum values with comparison in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I want to obtain minimum value for a group/unique key in JavaScript

```
var allPriceData = $('#allPriceData').val();
//  alert (allPriceData);   
// Data 801||264||15:801||264||10:801||265||18:801||265||20:801||265||18        
var arr = allPriceData.split(':');

for(var j=0;j<arr.length;j++) {
    alert(arr[j]);
    var array = arr[j].split('||');

    for(var k=0;k<array.length;k++) {

    // Need Code Here for Required result:       
   }
 }
```

here is a sample array

264||15

264||10

265||18

265||20

265||22

Required Answer :

264||10

265||18

thanks...

Comment: show some code with actual array structure

Comment: for(var j=0;j<arr.length;j++) {
    alert(arr[j]);
}
and it will alert

Comment: that isn't an array - if it were, you could use .reduce and some code

Comment: @JaromandaX , i've updated the Question...... thanks.

Comment: @JaromandaX
Please check and let me know,if other details required.. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done:

```
var energy = '264||0||10:265||0||0:266||265||1614.99:269||0||0:270||269||0';
alert(energy);

var small = ["264||0||15","265||0||0","268||265||20.99"];
alert(small);

var min_array = energy.split(':');
var sum = 0;
for(var r=0;r<min_array.length;r++) {
    var min_values = min_array[r].split('||');

    var n = 'false';
    for(var j=0;j<small.length;j++) {
        //  alert(x[j]);
        var temp = small[j].split('||');
        if (temp[0] == min_values[0] && temp[1] == min_values[1])
        {
            sum = parseFloat(sum) + parseFloat(temp[2]);
            n = 'true';         
        } 
        else if (temp[1] != 0 && temp[1] == min_values[1])
        {
            sum = parseFloat(sum) + parseFloat(temp[2]);
            n = 'true';
        }
    }
    if (n == 'false')
    {
        sum = parseFloat(sum) + parseFloat(min_values[2]);
    }
    alert('sum '+sum);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some assumptions on your data structure :

```js
var data = [
  [264, 15],
  [264, 10], 
  [265, 18], 
  [265, 20], 
  [265, 22]
]
var tempDict = data.reduce(function (_, tuple) {
  var k = tuple[0], val = tuple[1]
  if (!_.hasOwnProperty(k)) _[k] = val
  else _[k] = Math.min(_[k], val)
  return _
  }, {})


var min = Object.keys(tempDict).reduce(function (_, k) {
  _.push([parseInt(k), tempDict[k]])
  return _
  }, [])
```

Comment: Can you please update your answer , with my specified condition.? thanks

Answer (score -1):

UPDATED: Just add small modification to get the desired result.

```
    var allKeys = ["264||15", "264||10", "265||18", "265||20", "265||22"];   


    allKeys.sort(function(i,j){
      var n = parseInt(i.split("||")[1]);
      var m = parseInt(j.split("||")[1]);
      return n > m;
    });

    var result = [];
    var obj = {};

    allKeys.forEach(function(ele){
      var n = ele.split("||")[0];
      if(obj[n] === undefined){
        obj[n] = true;
        result.push(ele);
      } 
    });

    console.log(result);
//Prints -> [ '264||10', '265||18' ]
```

Comment: Need this //Prints -> [ '264||10', '265||18' ]